# One to many relationship table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, entity-relationship

There are two entities one of which is a weak entity and the relationship between them is one to many. The stable can have many cells but must have at least one, and the cell must be in only one stable.

```
CREATE TABLE Stables
(
    StableNr   SERIAL       NOT NULL,
    Address    VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
        ...
    PRIMARY KEY (StableNr),

);

CREATE TABLE Cell
(
    CellNr      SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    StableNr    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Spaces      SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        ...
    PRIMARY KEY (CellNr, StableNr),
    FOREIGN KEY (StableNr) REFERENCES Stables ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

How to make sure stables have at least one cell?

Comment: Have you tried parent child relations??

Comment: Add stable_id to Cell table. Then you could create multiple Cell for a single Stable entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce this kind of thing with constraint triggers:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

1. After insert into stables, verify that there exists a cell with the relevant stablenr.
2. After update on `cell (stablenr)` and after delete on cell, verify that there is still a cell with the old `stablenr` *or* that the stable no longer exists.

In each case, sure to make the triggers `deferrable initially deferred`, else you won't be able to insert, update or delete the rows to begin with.

With that said, I'd advise to not do it. In real life, your stable might be under construction, cells might be around and unavailable, the stable might have no cells and only a field, yada yada, or more simply you might be aware of a stable but not of the number of cells within it during data entry. Point is, any number of colorful scenarios may occur that violate this constraint.

By not enforcing the constraint, your schema and your app will gain flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I made this trigger and it works as it should. I did not use **deferrable initially deferred** since I don't really understand it completely. When making new stable it automatically inserts one new cell with (CellNr 1, StableNr, Spaces 1).

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertCell() RETURNS "trigger" AS $$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO cell VALUES (1, NEW.StableNr);
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER CellForStables
    AFTER INSERT ON Stables
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertCell();
```

It works, but did I miss anything important? Thank you!

Comment: This: it doesn't cover the case where the cell is deleted or its stablenr is updated to something else. What you did above is unwieldy in practice, in that it could just as well be part of a transaction where you might want to be inserting not just one but many cells: you'd then need to fetch the existing cell, update it if needed, and insert the additional ones... instead of simply inserting them.

Comment: I simply add ON UPDATE CASCADE to CELL table. And I will think of smth for not deleting the last cell too :) This is for an assignment and its ok if it not the most efficient way. Maybe you could show me   how to write a function/trigger for not deleting the one remaining cell in the stables or maybe there's a different way to do constrain this? I need to delete the stables in that situation.